# Can Gparted brick a drive?

Tags: partitioning, ssd, gparted

I tried to delete a LUKS volume on an M.2 NVMe drive by rewriting the partition table in Gparted. It failed stating "the Linux kernel wouldn't recognize a change until I rebooted"... or something along those lines. So I rebooted, but now my drive is unrecognizable by both the BIOS and any OS I've loaded (Windows, Gparted live, Linux with `fdisk -l`, etc.). Has this happened to anyone else? Is there anything I can do to recover the disk?

Comment: *Can Gparted brick a drive?*.... yes, you can brick it depending on what operations you perform. Have backups and understand what you are doing before you do it. If you don't understand 100% or are unsure, then don't do it or be prepared to recover from your backup.

Comment: Just to be clear, by "brick" I mean make the hardware itself unusable in any sense rather than lose the data on the disk.

Comment: No, Gparted cannot cause physical hardware damage to the drive.